# setup openldap push syncrepl

Tags: ldap, synchronization, push, openldap

actually I'm totally stuck in understanding how to setup an openldap push replication.

My scenario is the following:

having a master ldap on my internal network I would like to sync with an slave in my dmz. Due to security reasons the slave is nt able to initiate a communication to the master ldap. So basically:

ldap.lan > (push) > ldap.dmz

I checked the docs 18.3.5. Syncrepl Proxy 
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html but here only "localhost" is mentioned - for master as well as for the slave.

Sorry, I don't get where to put my ldap.lan and where to put my ldap.dmz

any help would be appreciated... maybe someone would even be able to provide a sample configuration to get my setup working...

thanx,

Mat